# Can we execute karate Gatling test in BlazeMeter?

Tags: karate, blazemeter

`val delete = scenario("delete").exec(karateFeature("classpath:mock/cats-delete.feature", "@name=delete"))`

When the above line is executed, at run time does karate build Gatling script (in Gatling way) for delete scenario ? ( I think no, because **"Karate is responsible for making HTTP requests while Gatling is only measuring the timings and managing threads"**

I am thinking is it possible to re-use karate tests(Gatling) run in [BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/) and/or with [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-gatling-and-taurus)

I know BlazeMeter can run Gatling tests but **cats-delete.feature** is a karate test not pure gatling script. So, I am wondering if can get Gatling script out of karate function test at run time.

It would be great if some one can shed some light here. ( I may be thinking completely wrong ! not sure)

Comment: @PeterThomas Sir, I am new to platform and this is my second question. I don't know how to 'accept' the answers. I am sorry for I did not 'accept' your answer for my first question. but I did vote up not sure if vote up and 'accept' are same. I will search on how to 'accept' answers in stack overflow and accept your answer.  By the way, I have voted for Karate and you in the HackerNoon "Noonies". I am fan of your work. Don't take me wrong in anyway.

Comment: @PeterThomas I Just 'accepted' your answer to my first question. I hope this makes you little less aggressive towards me :) Just learning stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Karate integration means that you create a Maven project using the Gatling Maven Plugin. As far as I know, it should "look" like a normal Gatling project to Blazemeter. So it should work. But I suggest you try it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts and suggestion. I will try and update here.